# почему файл css не добавился после collectstaic? python django

Tags: python, django, static

Не добавляется ccs в static файлы. Создал css файл в приложении prints/templates/css/print_style.css

**html prints/templates/prints/print.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block link %}
<link href="{% static 'css/print_style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
```

дальше manage.py collectstatic

обновляю сайт, пытаюсь открыть этот css файл и выдает ошибку `Page not found (404)`

Comment: Потому что templates это папка для шаблонов, а не для статических файлов

Comment: понял, создал папку static, заработало

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте это в ваш settings.py

```
# Настройки шаблонизатора
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Настройка медиафайлов и статики
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
```

Помимо этого `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` должен быть в ваших `INSTALLED_APPS`